# Outputting strings in Assembly?

Tags: assembly, io

I am really confused about outputting strings in Assembly. I have been told to use the "PUTS" Assembler Name to print characters to the console, but I am not sure how to use it.
Here is what I have so far, but it causes errors:

```
LD R1, MESS_ARR; Array in register 1
PUTS R1; Print out the string at first index
ADD R1,R1,1; Add to go to next memory location
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Assembler there is no real command for doing I/O.

Instead all devices have an address and you write the data to that address.

Example (here Assembler for ARM processors):

```
LR R0, =65  ; Load byte 65 ('A') into register 0
LR R1, =123456 ; Load 123456 into register 1
STB R1, [R0]  ; Write the value to address 123456
```

It depends on the computer (or simulator) to which address some data has to be written so the data will be written to the screen, the printer or any other device.

What you normally do is to call an existing sub-routine:

```
  LR R0, =65
  BL putc ; call sub-routine "putc"
  ...
  ; putc = write character in register R0
putc:
  LR R1, =123456 ; Load 123456 into register 1
  STB R1, [R0]  ; Write the value to address 123456
  MOV PC, LR ; Ret
```

Instructions for calling sub-routines are often named "CALL", "BL", "JL", "JRS", "BRS" (depending on the CPU)...

There are special variants named "INT", "BRK", "SWI", "SVC", "SYSCALL"... which are used for calling OS functions.

I would guess you use Assembler for MIPS processors so your program **might** work like this:

```
LR R3, MESS_ARR
JL puts
ADD R3,R3,1
```

However not knowing which kind of CPU you are working on and not knowing the operating system (or CPU emulator) it is nearly impossible to say if this code is correct.

(B.t.w: "putc" will output one character, "puts" will take an address of a string as input argument and output the whole string.)

Note that the name is typically case-sensitive so "puts", "PuTs" and "PUTS" are three completely different functions.

Comment: Thank you. I am using Linux. I found out that using TRAP x22 prints it to the console